# Need to look for a value and display the following cells on the other two textboxes

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want to search the value of TextBox1 in the column B of Sheet2. I have the same code on another userform and works but i made a new userform and is not working. Seems like Findleg is not bringing nothing.

Anyone can spot the error?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
Dim Findleg As Range
Dim leg As String

'Encontrar el legajo en la lista
leg = TextBox1.Value
Set Findleg = Hoja2.Range("B:B").Find(What:=leg, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

If Findleg Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "No se encuentra el legajo"

'Deja las casillas vacias cuando termina
TextBox1.Value = ""
TextBox2.Value = ""
TextBox3.Value = ""
TextBox4.Value = ""
Exit Sub

Else
TextBox2.Value = Findleg.Offset(0, 1)
TextBox3.Value = Findleg.Offset(0, 2)

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, i had hidden a button to press to check for that value and not a textbox exactly.